# Python scrapy cant start a project

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I failed to start a new project,but I don't know how to fix it.i input`scrapy startproject douban_new_movie`,the result is`ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_openssl)`

i have uninstall **scarpy**once , but it is not useful.

please tell me how to solve it,thank you.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 121, in execute
    cmds = _get_commands_dict(settings, inproject)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 45, in _get_commands_dict
    cmds = _get_commands_from_module('scrapy.commands', inproject)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 28, in _get_commands_from_module
    for cmd in _iter_command_classes(module):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 19, in _iter_command_classes
    for module in walk_modules(module_name):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/commands/version.py", line 6, in <module>
    import OpenSSL
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/rand.py", line 12, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 15, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib`

Comment: can you share the whole traceback? can you [re-installing `cryptography` package](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/)?

Comment: i have reinstall cryptography ,it still cant work well.